# header skewed when compiling WinEdt QuickGuide

Tags: winedt

for some reason, when I compile the WinEdtGuide.tex file[image], the header is skewed to one side.  Do you know if something in my environment got messed up?

As you can see above, the "Acknowledgements" is almost total cut off.  The header should look like this:

[image]

Can you tell me what is happening with my compilation of the WinEdt.tex file?

Comment: Works for me out of the box (after downloading the guide files)

Comment: Do you think it might have to do with an environment setting in win edit??  I am using PDFLaTeX to compile the tex file.

Comment: I was going through the log file and there was a warning...Package scrpage2 Warning:  You've set width of head to a value greater than width of page!.  In the code there is \setheadwidth[-7.5mm]{1.175\linewidth}.  Do you think that this could be the problem?  I am using a size A4 paper in the WinEdt settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that [WinEdt Quick Guide](http://www.winedt.com/doc/QuickGuide.zip) has been compiled with a KOMA-Script version prior to v3.17a.

If you have the latest version of KOMA-Script, you have to change the line

```
\setheadwidth[-7.5mm]{1.175\linewidth}
```

to

```
\setheadwidth[-7.5mm]{1.175\textwidth}
```

and the result will be as expected.

This change will be made as soon as possible in the downloadable guide, too.