# bibliography does not appear using QUickGuide.tex as a template

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using the `QuickGuide.tex` as a template and my bibliography for some reason does not appear.  If I uncomment the `\printbibliography` I get an error. Here is my code using PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[%
   ,paper=a4     
   ,pagesize=auto
   ,BCOR=0.75cm  
   ,DIV=10       
   ,numbers=noenddot 
   ,captions=heading 
   ,captions=nooneline 
   ,listof=totoc 
   ,bibliography=totoc 
   ,index=totoc  
   ,headings=normal 
   ,USenglish,  
]{scrbook}

\newcommand*{\VersionInformation}{%
   \centering{%
      WinEdt Version \version\par
      Typeset with \LaTeXe\ and \KOMAScript\ class\par
      using \textrm{Palatino} and \textsf{Bera} fonts.\par
   {\scriptsize generated: \today\par}}
}

\usepackage[%
             ,headsepline
             ,footsepline
             ,plainfootsepline
            ]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setheadwidth[-7.5mm]{1.175\textwidth}
%
% headline color
\setheadsepline{.5pt}[\color{Navy}]
\setfootsepline{.5pt}[\color{Navy}]

\newcommand*{\ORIGchapterheadstartvskip}{}%

\let\ORIGchapterheadstartvskip=\chapterheadstartvskip

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{%
  \ORIGchapterheadstartvskip
  {\color{Navy}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \noindent\rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
  }%
}
% see above
\newcommand*{\ORIGchapterheadendvskip}{}%
\let\ORIGchapterheadendvskip=\chapterheadendvskip
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{%
  {\color{Navy}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \noindent\rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par
  }%
  \ORIGchapterheadendvskip
}

\usepackage{marvosym}
%
%% ============================================================================
%% Macros etc:
%
%
%% LaTeX fixes and basics
\usepackage{%
            ,fix-cm     % fix-cm package for LaTeX (c) Walter Schmidt 2003
%            ,fix2col    % bugfix for colum layout
            ,etex       % extended number of variables and links
            ,thinsp     % stretchable \thinspace (\,)
            ,xspace     % variable space
%            ,ifthen
            ,calc       % calculating
            }
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\usepackage{babel}      % language support
%
% line break after /:
    \defineshorthand{"/}{\slash}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % EC fonts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % coding UTF-8

%
%% ============================================================================
% colors
\usepackage[%
            ,showerrors%
            ,svgnames%
            ,table% colors in tables
           ]{xcolor}
%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{%
            ,graphicx           % graphics
            ,rotating           % rotating of text etc.
            ,ltablex            % extended functionality for tables
%                               % combines and loads 'longtable' and 'tabularx' automatically,
%                               % tabularx loads array
            ,dcolumn            % horizontal alignment in tabular cells at decimal dot
            ,booktabs           % extended lines for tables
           }

    \usepackage{siunitx}
%

    \renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}% Standard = 0.5
    \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.15}% Standard = 0.2

    \renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.8}% Standard = 0.7
    \setcounter{topnumber}{3} % vorher: 2
    \setcounter{bottomnumber}{1} % vorher: 1
    \setcounter{totalnumber}{5} % vorher: 3

    \renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.8}% Standard = 0.7
    \renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.6}% Standard = 0.5
%

    \tolerance 1414
    \hbadness 1414
    \emergencystretch 1.5em
    \hfuzz 0.3pt
    \widowpenalty = 2500
    \displaywidowpenalty = 2500
    \vfuzz \hfuzz
    \raggedbottom
\DeclareOption{tanz}{\raggedbottom}

    \ProcessOptions\relax

  \deffootnote{2.25em}{1.75em}{\thefootnotemark.\enspace}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn% syntax of expl3 on
%
\cs_new_eq:Nc \emph_old:n { emph~ } % Copying the old definition of `\emph`
\cs_new_eq:NN \emph_braces:n \textup % Braces should be typeset upright.
%
\cs_new:Npn \emph_new:n #1 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_emph_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {(}{\emph_braces:n{(}}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {)}{\emph_braces:n{)}}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {[}{\emph_braces:n{[}}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {]}{\emph_braces:n{]}}
  \exp_args:NV \emph_old:n \l_emph_tl
}
%
% \emph umdefinieren, Sternvariante mit altem (=kursivem) Verhalten
\RenewDocumentCommand {\emph} {sm} {
  \IfBooleanTF {#1} {\emph_old:n {#2}} {\emph_new:n {#2}}
}
%
\ExplSyntaxOff% syntax of expl3 on
%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% dates in ISO format
\usepackage[iso]{isodate}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% line breaks in URLs at "-"
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% PDF settings
\ifpdfoutput{% needs a KOMA-Script class!!!

   \usepackage[%
               ,final
               ,kerning
               ,babel
               ,protrusion=true
               ,expansion=true % better typography, but with much larger PDF file
               ,tracking=true
              ]{microtype}
   \DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}{ font = */*/*/sc/* }%
      \SetTracking{ encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 45 }

   \usepackage[%
               ,pdftex%
               ,plainpages=false%
               ,colorlinks%
               ,linkcolor={Navy}%
               ,citecolor={Navy}%
               ,linktocpage={true}%
               ,breaklinks%
               ,pdfcreator={pdflatex}%
               ,pdfstartview=FitH
               ,bookmarksopen=true% book marks in PDF reader
               ]{hyperref}
%
\usepackage{bookmark}% bookmark cleanup
}%
%% -----------------------------------
%% non-PDF branch
{%
   \usepackage[%
               ,xetex%hypertex
               ,linktocpage={true}%
               ,breaklinks%
               ]{hyperref}
%
% optimized margin alignment with microtype:
   \usepackage[%
               ,final
               ,DVIoutput
               %,kerning
               ,babel
               ,protrusion=true
              ]{microtype}
}
%
\usepackage[figure]{hypcap} % links to the upper edge of floating environments
%
%% ============================================================================
% extended handling of figures
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%
%% ============================================================================
% intelligent cross references
\usepackage{cleveref}
%% ============================================================================
% Fonts
\usepackage{textcomp} % Text Companion fonts which provide many text symbols in the TS1 encoding.
%
%% -- Palatino with Bera fonts
    \linespread{1.05}\selectfont      % line spread for Palatino
    \usepackage[scaled=.88]{beramono} % Bera-Monospace
    \usepackage[scaled=.86]{berasans} % Bera Sans-Serif
    \usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}     % Palatino with small caps and minuscel numbers

\usepackage{amsmath}

   \usepackage{fixmath}

   \typearea[current]{last}    % with DIV=[number]

\usepackage{textcomp} % required for \texteuro
\usepackage{eurosym}  % required for \euro
\catcode`\=13
\def{•} % WinEdt bullet (U+007F)-> Unicode Bullet (U+2022)
%% ============================================================================
\usepackage{lscape} %landscape pages support


%% ============================================================================


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Version Information  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\version}{9.1 (2015-05-17)}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\WinEdtCmd}[1]{\textcolor{CornflowerBlue}{\textsf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\WinEdtKey}[1]{\textcolor{LightSeaGreen}{\textsf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\WinEdtFile}[1]{\textcolor{DarkSlateGray}{\texttt{#1}}}

%========================================================================================
%   Bibliography
%========================================================================================

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}   \addbibresource{../References/chap1.bib}% BibTeX
 \defbibheading{bibempty}{}
 \newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}


% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document Starts here:
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%% ============================================================================
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=plain}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\centering}% all caption lines as multilines
%% ============================================================================

\frontmatter

\subject{\ }
\title{WinEdt}
\subtitle{Quick Guide}
\author{\textsc{Aleksander Simonič}\\ \small{\copyright~1993--2015}}
\date{}
%
\lowertitleback{\VersionInformation}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
This chapter give you an idea of how the reference is not showing up \cite{egan}

\backmatter

\lohead[]{}

%\printbibliography
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=\bibname]
\subsection*{Books}
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book, title={Books}]
%\subsection*{Online}
%\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibintoc, title={Online}]
%\subsection*{Articles}
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={Articles}]

\end{document}
```

Here is the example of my `chap1.bib` file that I place in the "References" folder:

```
@book{egan,
 address = {New York},
 publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
 author = {Egan, Willian F.},
 title = {Phase-Lock Basics},
 year = {1998},
 %volume = {3},
 %series = {2},
 edition = {1},
 pages = {3--4},
 %month = {January}
}
```

Can you tell me how I can get the bibliography to show up correctly?

This is what the biber file looks like:

```
[0] Config.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[0] Config.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'EEL6935_Estimation_Theory_HW1.blg'
[184] biber-MSWIN:273> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[185] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'EEL6935_Estimation_Theory_HW1.bcf'
[564] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[565] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 1
[565] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[565] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 2
[565] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[566] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 3
[566] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[754] Biber.pm:2977> INFO - Processing section 1
[968] Biber.pm:3115> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'chap1.bib' for section 1
[1436] bibtex.pm:1021> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[1455] bibtex.pm:895> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'C:/Users/ers045/Desktop/EEL6935/EEL6935_Estimation_Theory/chap1.bib'
[1626] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[1627] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[1627] Biber.pm:2854> INFO - Sorting list 'none' of type 'entry' with scheme 'none' and locale 'en-US'
[1627] Biber.pm:2858> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
[1631] bbl.pm:505> INFO - Writing 'EEL6935_Estimation_Theory_HW1.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[1646] bbl.pm:596> INFO - Output to EEL6935_Estimation_Theory_HW1.bbl
```

Note that I changed the file name to "EEL6935_Estimation_Theory_HW1".

Comment: For some reason you make `=` an active character (line 241 with `\catcode\`\=13`), if you just let `=` be its usual inactive self, you don't get any errors regarding `biblatex` any more (I only got one about `\def{•}`). Does removing that line work for you? What errors do you get?

Comment: Note that lots of code there is probably specific to the original document. It probably is not the best idea to use that document as a template. See also [Making WinEdt QuickGuide.tex work with XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251046/35864), in [header skewed when compiling WinEdt QuickGuide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249019/35864) it even seems that at least at some point the document used outdated packages, so you might run into trouble there as well.

Comment: You will find that `\newcommand*{\VersionInformation}` is probably not needed if you write your own document. There are other commands floating around there that I would consider not really necessary for you if you don't want to simply re-write the guide. Also the `scrpage2` package is considered obsolete. And I doubt you will ever use the functionality of all of those packages included, you could probably let a lot of them go.

Comment: Hello,  I made some of the changes that you suggested.  I am able to not get any errors now, however, the bibliography still does not appear after I run PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Have you made sure you run Biber (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)). Do you get any interesting output in your `.log` file? What does the `.blg` file look like, if you can run Biber?

Comment: The `.blg` file looks fine. Does the `.log` say anything weird?

Comment: Hello @moewe, you have me thinking now that if the scrpage2 is considered obsolete, can you help me convert the code then using the fancyheader?  Would this make it easier for us?

Comment: No, this should have no bearing on `biblatex` whatsoever if the document compiles at all (which it does). Read about [`scrpage2` here](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=scrpage2), where you can find that it is succeeded by [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf). If you use `scrbook`, `fancyhdr` might not be the best idea: "In place of `scrpage2` or `scrlayer-scrpage` you can of course make use of `fancyhdr`. However,
`scrpage2` and especially `scrlayer-scrpage` integrated markedly better with the KOMA-Script bundle." (p. E.3 of the `scrpage2` guide)

Comment: If you are lucky, you might be able to convert to `scrlayer-scrpage` without a lot of changing of commands. If you need more help setting up header and footers, I suggest you ask a separate question for that.

Comment: I found this in the log file: `Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def")
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.`. Does this mean anything?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything bad, no. Did you run pdfLaTeX again after running Biber? What does the last bit before the "Here is how much of TeX's memory you used" that mentions `biblatex` say? Can you find a mention of the `.bbl` in the `.log` file, what does it say?

Comment: You are also loading some packages twice. (In addition to loading a lot of stuff which you probably don't want.) If you don't know why you are loading a package, remove it and see if it was doing anything good. Most of the stuff you are loading is probably just going to cause you grief in the form of weird, mysterious unwanted effects on your document or equally mysterious errors.

Comment: Don't change the file name by deleting its extension! Biblatex relies on that extension to find the file. If you delete the extension, then obviously it is not going to find your bibliography and you will not, indeed, get a bibliography. What is the definition of the empty header thing for? Do you need that?

Comment: Did you get anywhere? My best guess is that you did not run the correct sequence of commands (LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX). But it is really hard to tell like this. Did you make sure that you run the commands? Can you report the `.log` file of the last LaTeX run as asked above (find lines mentioning `.bbl` and the last bit about `biblatex`)?

Comment: @moewe, thanks for checking up...I have the log file, but how can I send that to you?

Comment: @moewe here are some of the comments:`Package biblatex Info: ... file 'references.bbl' found.

(references.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 270.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 270.`..`Package biblatex Info: Reference section=1 on input line 295.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsection:1' on input line 295.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'egan' on page 1 undefined on input line 296.
[1] [2]
Package biblatex Warning: Type 'book' not found on input line 305.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 305.`

Comment: You can add the relevant parts of the `.log` file to your question. I notice that again the name of your file seems to have changed (`references` vs `EEL6935_Estimation_Theory_HW1`). Please make sure to compile the same document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX and then report the findings of the `.blg` and `.log` files. What does the `.bbl` file contain? Have you ever successfully been able to compile a minimal `biblatex` example? Such as the one [here](http://texwelt.de/blog/hilfe-zu-biblatex/), the site is in German, sorry, but I only want you to try out the example.

Comment: For the example that you pointed me to, on the German website, I was able to compile it successfully.  I saw the references show up in the document after running PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe, I went to website `https://www.queryxchange.com/q/24_249427/bibliography-in-scrbook/` and found a solution for the problem that I am having.  The solution given here fixed my problem. Thank you for all your time and help!

Comment: I am just a little bit confused here. First of all, as you are the very same poster of both question? Second of all. i think i recognize the answer there.

Comment: @moewe, I sincerely apologize for taking up your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution given in [bibliography in scrbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249427/) solves the original problem posted here.